# How to add cancel button to spinner dialog?

Tags: android, spinner

I have a `spinner` with its mode set to `dialog`:

```
        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/spinner1"
            android:spinnerMode="dialog"
            android:dropDownWidth="match_parent"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Medium"
            android:prompt="@string/label_selection" />
```

How can I a Cancel button to its dialog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way is to create your own custom spinner, like:

```
public class MySpinner extends Spinner implements OnClickListener {
   //blah-blah
}
```

Important things need to be implemented:

1. `protected onDraw()` - which would actually draw your `MySpinner` + button
2. `protected void onMeasure(int widthSpec, int heightSpec)` - defines size of your custom spinner

[Here's a link](http://www.skill-guru.com/blog/2011/01/20/creating-a-custom-widgets-in-android/) to tutorial which covers basics of custom widgets